# Phonegap & Firebase Google Auth Problems

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, phonegap-build, firebase-authentication

So I'm creating a android phonegap app and I'm trying to integrate Firebase.

I added the web app code from Firebase and called `firebase.auth()` then I would get the error:

```
"Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth
?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.ne…tp://axschema.org/namePerson
/last&openid.ax.required=email,name,first,last'
in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."
```

I've done a bunch of research but if there was a solution I couldn't understand it because they didn't explain it fully.

I also have inappbrowser installed if that helps?

Here is my code:  PS I removed some code to focus on the login section

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"/>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/swiper.min.css"/>
    <title>SUSU</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="outer-content">
            <div class="pages">
                <div id="login" class="page">
                    <div class="logo"></div>
                    <h1>LOGIN OR REGISTER</h1>
                    <div class="facebook-btn">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <span class="icon icon-plus"></span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="text">Sign in with Facebook</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="google-btn" onclick="googleLogin()">
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <span class="icon icon-plus"></span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="text">Sign in with Google</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    navigator.splashscreen.show();
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 5000);
},true);

var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
function googleLogin(){

    //var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');

    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function(result) {
        console.log(provider, result);
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        var user = result.user;
        // ...
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        var email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        var credential = error.credential;
        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: If I'm missing any info please let me know

Comment: signInWithRedirect and signInWithPopup is currently not supported in firebase 3.x in Cordova, you will have to use a Google plugin to get the OAuth token and then call signInWithCredential to sign in to Firebase with that OAuth credential.

Comment: Okay soI'm following a google tutorial on Oauth.  My only problem is that I need to set up my app within Google Apis and I can either select a web app and give a url or select a android app and give a Signing-certificate-fingerprint.  I'm not sure which way to go since this isn't a true web app or android app?

Comment: EDIT:  I got the same error "Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=storagerelay%3A%2F%2…omain=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.8%3A3000&fetch_basic_profile=true&gsiwebsdk=2' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

Comment: Hey @bojeil, I've been trying to figure this out and I'm extreemly lost.  I'm sorry to bother you, but can you give me a little more guidance?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. The flow (web app or android app) depends on the plugin you are using to get the access token. It doesn't matter to firebase how you get the access token. signInWithCredential will work without caring how you got that token as long as it belongs to the same project.

Comment: Hey Bojeil, no worries.  I ended up switching to Ionic because it has built in firebase capabilities.

Comment: @MatMorse i'm encountering same problem i'm using simple bootstrap+firebase+phonegap(android) can you tell how did it got solved ?